# Configure Tesseract with solr 6.4.1

Tags: solr, solr4, apache-tika, sunspot-solr

How to configure Tika OCR with solr 6.4.1.
I indexed documents including PDF, images and MS office documents but problem was occurred Tika was not extracting text from images and also from images which are inside PDF and MS office documents. for this I researched Tika OCR is used.
for this purpose i am installing tika-app-1.7.jar and Tesseract but i don't know how to configure them with my solr core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. Simply get the Tesseract OCR setup for your distro and [install](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaOCR)  it on the system. Make sure your `PATH` variable has an entry for the Tesseract home directory, and the `TESSDATA_PREFIX` variable is set and also points to the Tesseract home directory. Restart Solr and you're good to go. You should be able to see the OCR component when you push documents to the index through the `/update/extract` handler.

By default, Tesseract only ships with the English model. Get models for other languages from [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files).

Comment: But it doesn't get arabic text .

Comment: How can i extract those ?

Comment: And also one thing more how can it extract text from images which are inside pdf and MS office documents ?

Comment: You need to download additional language packs for arabic.

Comment: if tika extracts the images and separates them from the doc, which i think it does, then this should happen automatically. I am not sure though so check the documentation on tika.