# solr tika configuration of tesseract for text extraction from image

Tags: image, solr, tesseract, apache-tika

I am configuring solr to extract text from image. I installed tesseractOCR and added path to TesseractOCRConfig.properties of tika-parser jar. But I am unable to extract text from image.
When I run it using tesseract to extract image, it working fine. Is there any way I can test with tika jar to test whether its calling tesseract properly or not.
I tried configuring on 2 windows machine, but no luck.
In solr even I can find following in for parsed_by,
`org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser,
org.apache.tika.parser.ocr.TesseractOCRParser,
org.apache.tika.parser.image.ImageParser`

property file:
    tesseractPath=E:/solr/Tesseract-OCR
    language=eng
Do I need to download and start tika-server-1.23.jar?
I saw all possible available links, could not found anything that is working for me.

Comment: May be this could help.. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59986034/solr-tika-configuration-of-tesseract-for-text-extraction-from-image

Comment: @Aswath you copied this issue link itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017921/configure-tesseract-with-solr-6-4-1

Sorry. Looks like a clipboard issue. Here is the correct link.