# Apache Solr 9.0 OCR of Image Saved As PDF

Tags: pdf, solr, ocr, solrj, apache-tika

I've got solr 9.0 running with the a request handler set up for Tika per https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/indexing-with-tika.html.

If I pass in a pdf document (that is, a text document that is stored as a PDF), I get the expected results of being able to query for the content of the document.

If, however, I pass in a pdf that is an image (it is a scanned page from a newsletter, then saved as a PDF), no OCR is taking place.  I'm using solrj to communicate with the solr install.

I also tried indexing the PDF after it was exported as a PNG. This worked testing with locally running tika, but not with solr.

```
fun index(file: File) {
        val urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/films"
        val solr = HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build()
        solr.parser = XMLResponseParser()
        val req = ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract")

        // I've tried both "image/pdf" and "application/pdf"
        req.addFile(file, "image/pdf")
        req.setParam("literal.id", file.name);
        req.setAction(ACTION.COMMIT, true, true)
        val result = solr.request(req)

        println("Result: $result")
    }
```

solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract"
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>

      <!-- capture link hrefs but ignore div attributes -->
      <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.a">links</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

I decided to test in isolation with tika, so I started the docker container

```
docker run -it \
    --name tika-server-ocr \
    -d \
    -p 9998:9998 \
    apache/tika:1.24-full
```

If I passed in the file as a PDF, it did not work:

```
curl -T "285 October-5.pdf" http://localhost:9998/tika
```

If I pass in an exported png from the PDF, it does work:

```
curl -T "285 October-5 copy.png" http://localhost:9998/tika
NEGOTIATING GARRY'S ANCHORAGE

Garry's Anchorage is a popular rest spot on the western
```

I'm guessing there is a bit of config or perhaps a parameter I need to send in to solr during the extraction?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017921/configure-tesseract-with-solr-6-4-1 ?

Comment: My understanding is that tika is now bundled in with solr, and that tesseract integrates with tika.  I'm wondering if I somehow need to enable tesseract for the embedded tika that is in solr?

Comment: Tika has been bundled with Solr for a long time, yes. The question I linked explains how to enable tesseract for the embedded Tika (install tesseract, make sure tesseract is in the path, and set the `TESSERACT_PATH` environment variable for Solr)

Comment: You need to specify that it should ocr in pdf, I am not sure how you set that setting when doing it through Solr https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/tika/TikaOCR#TikaOCR-OCRandPDFs

Answer (score 0):

The default configuaration for scanning of PDF in Tika is `ocrStrategy` set to `no_ocr`.

To change this in Solr you will want to locate `tika-parsers-*.jar` that should be in your `\modules\extraction\lib` lib.

Inside the jar you can find the `PDFParser.properties` located in the folder `\org\apache\tika\parser\pdf\`

Update the config for `ocrStrategy` that is set to `no_ocr` by default. Options are as followers: `no_ocr`, `ocr_only`, `ocr_and_text_extraction`, `auto`